# FTP setting to block CD command

Tags: linux

I want to block the "cd " command from run in remote server via FTP connection.

I am using "HELiOS release 6.5.2 (Carbon) "  version.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could change from ftp server to ftp server. You probably want to jail users to their homes.

on VSFTPD check for the existence of: chroot_local_user=YES

On VSFTP has you mentioned on your comment you can use cmds_Allowed:

```
cmds_allowed=ABOR,APPE,CWD,DELE,HELP,LIST,MDTM,MKD,NLST,PASS,PASV,PWD,QUIT,RETR,RMD,RNFR,RNTO,SIZE,STOR,TYPE,USER
```

The FTP command to change directory is CWD, for delete is DELE

so:

```
cmds_allowed=ABOR,APPE,HELP,LIST,MDTM,MKD,NLST,PASS,PASV,PWD,QUIT,RETR,RMD,RNFR,RNTO,SIZE,STOR,TYPE,USER
```

"

or:

```
cmds_denied=CWD
```

Comment: i have requirement like this. i have a predefined setting. once you do ftp , it will take you to that path automatically. from that path you can get the required file. i do not want to allow the user  to change the directory & remove file option during ftp session.i want to restrict some commands for ftp users.

Comment: i found cmds_allowed & cmds_denied two options which could be used . but am not able to understand this.